Mason Bricks dynamic views with directories from args with loop
I am using Mason Bricks.
I know, you can also have loop in files. But is there also a way to use loops to create files from given args?
This is the structure I would like to accomplish:
my_example_flow/
├── view.dart               # Contains the MyExampleFlow class
└── views/
    ├── view_1/
    │   └── view.dart       # Contains class MyExampleFlowView1
    ├── view_2/
    │   └── view.dart       # Contains class MyExampleFlowView2
    └── view_3/
        └── view.dart       # Contains class MyExampleFlowView3

But the number of views should be dynamic.
My yaml currently looks like this:
name: view_brick
description: Generates views and a flow structure
version: 0.1.0+1
environment:
  mason: ">=0.1.0-dev.41 <0.1.0"

vars:
  flow_name:
    type: string
    description: "The name of the general flow"
  views:
    type: list
    description: "Comma-separated list of views (PascalCase, e.g. View1,View2)"

But I am stuck now. How do I get the above structure? Let me know if you need any more information! Is something like this even possible with mason?
Update:
I also tried adding \  instead of / as per @Randals's suggestion. This is what it looks like:

But still, no error, but it's only generating:
my_example_flow/
  ├── view.dart 


Yes, it's possible, but tricky.   Pull up the source code for the Very Good CLI to see how they are using mason to generate the various forms of dart or flutter projects.  They do tricks like use conditionals in filenames.  I copied some of those tricks for my "codepad" brick (in the brickyard).

@RandalSchwartz I tried it but failed... I tried things like naming the file {{#createFile}}views/{{view.snakeCase()}}/view.dart{{/createFile}} but it's just not working, always just creating the parent folder.

You have to end a conditional differently to avoid a / in your filename.  Just replace it with \ instead.  Not sure why that works, but I saw the trick in the VGV stuff.

@RandalSchwartz updated the question, still not working :(
